# Best way to stop scrollbar from interfering

Tags: html, css

I am currently doing a popup for when a person adds products to their cart, but I have a problem with making it responsive.

The problem is when a users browser's height is smaller than the popup, the `overflow` css property adds the ability to scroll (which is what i want), but it also adds its own width inside the popup, causing one product to move down to next line. I would like a way to add that scrollbar all the way to the right (so it looks like a normal page scroller).

I made a simplified example here: http://codepen.io/Mathias_/pen/oLyVQj
(The problem is not that the white box dosn't cover the enitre product, but when you make the browser height smaller one product move onto next line)

Comment: Scrollbars will always add a tiny amount of width. The best thing you could do is design your car page so that it doesn't push an item down (make your cart page slightly more narrow?)

Comment: Overflow isn't your problem (in this codepen). With `overflow: hidden` the third product is still pushed down. Rethink your layout, set widths in % instead of pixels maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akKxdO)

i added `overflow:auto` to your `.bottom-box` class.

Comment: That still dosn't solve the problem, if you look at my pen again I changed the colors of the li so its easier to see (imagine each li is a different product). In your example the product is still not all on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one:
`enter code here`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZKJgx
I'm not sure but may be padding with the less amount may help? I've set 10px.

Answer (score 0):

You can also only use coordonates to size your popup. *(height:100% + top:15px; is of couse too much to sit in the window)*

Update your popup css with this and test it

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 830px;
    bottom:15px;/* or 0 or whatever */
    margin-left: -415px;
    z-index: 16000004;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/grKyKj)